# VMware Fusion 12 Shared Folders

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have Fusion 12 and Windows 10 VM installed on my Mac (Big Sur).  I've also installed the Windows version of QMF for Workstation 12.1 (as the Mac version does not support Big Sur).  When setting up QMF it attempts to create a directory in the VMware Shared Folders giving the error below.  Is there a way to allow this?

[image]